# can custom C++ classes replicate the performance of inbuilt types?

Tags: c++, embedded, stack, operator-overloading

I am trying to create a C++ class that behaves exactly like the inbuilt `int` type with one exception: everywhere that operator* (or operator*=) is called, addition is called instead.

At first, the performance of my class was very poor (1/2 that of the inbuilt `int` type), but I noticed this was because I forgot to include the copy constructor below:

```
struct AlmostInt {                                                                                                                                                                       

  AlmostInt () { }                
  AlmostInt (const AlmostInt  &a) : val(a.val) { }  // forgetting this killed
                                                    // performance

  AlmostInt operator+(const AlmostInt &a) const { AlmostInt result = *this;
                                          result.val += a.val;
                                          return result; }
  AlmostInt operator-(const AlmostInt &a) const { AlmostInt result = *this;
                                          result.val -= a.val;
                                          return result; }
  AlmostInt operator*(const AlmostInt &a) const { AlmostInt result = *this;
                                          result.val  = result.val + a.val;      
                                          return result; }
  AlmostInt &operator+=(const AlmostInt &a) { this->val += a.val;                           
                                              return *this; }
  AlmostInt &operator-=(const AlmostInt &a) { this->val -= a.val;        
                                              return *this; }
  AlmostInt &operator*=(const AlmostInt &a) { this->val = this->val + a.val);     
                                              return *this; }

private:
  int val;
};
```

Unfortunately, my program remains 25% slower than it should be. Examining the assembly generated for the two different versions of the program (one using `int`, the other using `AlmostInt`), I see that there is an identical number of + and - operations, so things are "working" at some level.

The problem is that there are significantly more load and store operations in the code using the `AlmostInt` class and not the native `int` operation.

Does anyone have any ideas on where this overhead might be coming from? The only guess
I had was that perhaps the compiler doesn't understand that `AlmostInt` has all the
same properties `int` does (e.g. associativity, commutativity), but if this were really
a problem, I would have expected a different number of '+' or '-' instructions in the code, and this doesn't happen.

I suspect that the additional loads and stores are related to extra stack activity, but
all I can say at this point is it isn't merely a few extra stack loads and stores at the
top and bottom of each function, but the extra loads and stores occur throughout the code.

Any ideas? I wonder if anyone can point me to a compiler that *does* allow
one to reach `int`'s level of performance with a custom class.

UPDATE:

Here is a simple function you can cut and paste to see what's going on for yourself. On x86-64 Linux (g++ 4.3, 4.4), AIX6 xlC and a couple of other platforms, changing the 'CHOOSE ONE...' lines below *should* lead to the same code being generated (or at least code of the same performance), but in practice the code bloats significantly. Can anyone explain what is going on (for any particular platform/compiler), or how to fix it?

```
class AlmostInt
{
    int value;

public:

    AlmostInt& operator+=(AlmostInt that)
    {
        value += that.value;
        return *this;
    }

    AlmostInt& operator-=(AlmostInt that)
    {
        value -= that.value;
        return *this;
    }

        AlmostInt& operator*=(AlmostInt that)
    {
        value *= that.value;
        return *this;
    }
};

AlmostInt operator+(AlmostInt lhs, AlmostInt rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}

AlmostInt operator-(AlmostInt lhs, AlmostInt rhs)
{
    lhs -= rhs;
    return lhs;
}

AlmostInt operator*(AlmostInt lhs, AlmostInt rhs)
{
    lhs *= rhs;
    return lhs;
}

// CHOOSE ONE OF THE FOLLOWING TWO LINES:
//typedef int real;
typedef AlmostInt real;

typedef struct {
  real re;
  real im;
} complex;

#define R(a0,a1,b0,b1,wre,wim) { \
  t1 = a0 - a1;  t2 = b0 - b1; \
  t5 = t1 * wim; t6 = t2 * wim; \
  t3 = a0;  t1 *= wre; \
  t3 += a1; t2 *= wre; \
  t1 -= t6; t4 = b0; \
  t2 += t5; t4 += b1; \
  a0 = t3;  b1 = t2; \
  a1 = t4;  b0 = t1; \
}

#define RZERO(a0,a1,b0,b1) { \
  t1 = a0 - a1; t2 = b0 - b1; \
  t3 = a0 + a1; t4 = b0 + b1; \
  b0 = t1; a0 = t3; \
  b1 = t2; a1 = t4; \
}

void rpass(real *a, const complex *w, unsigned int n)
{
  real t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8;
  real *b;
  unsigned int k;

  b = a + 4 * n;
  k = n - 2;

  RZERO(a[0],a[1],b[0],b[1]);
  R(a[2],a[3],b[2],b[3],w[0].re,w[0].im);
  R(a[4],a[5],b[4],b[5],w[1].re,w[1].im);
  R(a[6],a[7],b[6],b[7],w[2].re,w[2].im);

  for (;;) {
    R(a[8],a[9],b[8],b[9],w[3].re,w[3].im);
    R(a[10],a[11],b[10],b[11],w[4].re,w[4].im);
    R(a[12],a[13],b[12],b[13],w[5].re,w[5].im);
    R(a[14],a[15],b[14],b[15],w[6].re,w[6].im);
    if (!(k -= 2)) break;
    a += 8;
    b += 8;
    w += 4;
  }
}
```

(Credit where credit's due: this little benchmark comes from the 'djbfft' library by Dan Bernstein)

Comment: What compiler are you using ? And how are you measuring performance ?

Comment: Especially built in types as int have manually optimized ASM instructions, some compilers met get you very close, but you're probably going to have to rewrite parts in assembly. However why would you ever turn multiply into addition?

Comment: @Paul R: Unfortunately, the answer here is pretty nasty. I'm doing embedded development with a compiler vendor that won't even let me talk about it. What I can say is it is derived from G++ 4.2 and runs on Linux. I'm measuring performance by compiling (and running) a single function (about 150 lines of C/C++) which is the inner loop of an FFT code.

Comment: Did you profile in Debug or Release mode?

Comment: What level of optimisation did you use?

Comment: @Roy T. : I have no problem rewriting the custom class in 100% assembly if need be. I don't know that that would improve performance though, since many compilers I have seen start giving up on lots of optimizations once they encounter intline asm frequently. If you mean "just write the important functions of the actual program in assembly", there's no point: I get optimal performance using plain C already, it's just ugly because I have to use function calls everywhere instead of operators. I guess I could have titled this question "is zero-overhead operator overloading possible?"

Comment: @Fred: "release mode" (g++ -O3)

Comment: @Nawaz, @Roy T.: I didn't tell you the whole story, because it's _very_ long, and you would get _very_ sad reading it all. However, if you're wondering why on earth you would ever replace multiply with addition, here's a little treat: if you _also_ replace addition with the min() function, you end up in a tropical wonderland. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_geometry

Comment: It surprising the performance you are getting. Since the class contaisns only a single int and all the functions are in-lineable I would expect you to get exactly the same performance. **Assuming** you have turned optimization on. -O3. Running code **once** is not a reliable way of timing. Run the loop **10,000** times and see if you get a difference.

Comment: @Martin: that's what you'd expect, but it isn't what you get. Try it yourself and see. Take any program that makes serious use of `int` arithmetic, and try replacing all such ints with AlmostInts. (You can even make the AlmostInt `operator*` just call integer *, i.e. make it behave identically to `int`.)

Comment: If writing your own trivial copy constructor is faster than letting the compiler provide one for you, then something is seriously wrong... Anyway, apart from the copy constructor, why are you passing by reference-to-const instead of by-value? Have you tried replacing `const AlmostInt&` with `AlmostInt`?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Sorry, no idea why the copy constructor helped as much as it did (I didn't really look into it). The pass-by-reference-to-const is just a relic of a failed attempt at more speed. I've just replaced `const AlmostInt &` with `AlmostInt` and the resulting assembly is bit-for-bit identical.

Comment: I refuse to answer this on grounds of sanity. What a horrendous abuse of the privilege of operator overloading. Please ensure that I never have to use your products.

Comment: @Tomalak: Are you implying that you actually _can_ answer the question in the title, but are refusing to on the grounds of sanity? I'm sorry you find this question insane. :(

Comment: @Fumiyo: Without further though I'm not convinced that I could produce a satisfactory answer, no, so you're not missing out. But if I could, I wouldn't post it. `op*` for addition? What!?!

Comment: @Fumiyo so how do you run the benchmark code? What valid arguments are we suppose to pass to `rpass()`?

Comment: @Victor T. : try calling rpass(a, b, 4); where a and b are of type real[32]. Then just call this function a million times. The code bloat is observable statically though, since there is no control flow (basically) you can see the speed difference just by looking at the assembly.

Answer (score 3):

One of most frequent reason for performance loss in these sort of cases
is returning values from functions.  In theory, a compiler should be
able to optimize this, and do the same thing as if you returned an `int`
(provided that all relevant functions are inlined); in practice, all of
the compilers I know will return an `int` in a register, but for a class
type, will pass an additional hidden argument with the address of a
temporary, and return the value in memory at this address.  The reason
is that things like the copy constructor or assignment require an
address (the this pointer, the reference to what is being copied), and
the compiler doesn't seem to recognize that once it's inlined all of the
functions, the address won't be necessary any more.  (There's also the
fact that the binary API says to do it this way, but the binary API
typically only concerns structures, not types with non-trivial
constructors, destructors and assignment operators.)

Comment: James, that sounds very plausible. The compiler is indeed inlining all functions. I guess the compiler isn't reaping the unnecessary stack activity because it is trying to comply with some kind of ABI. I wonder how to check?

Comment: @Fumiyo Eda Look at the generated assembler.

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of the constructors, replace call by reference-to-const with call by value (because the `AlmostInt` objects are really small), and implement the non-modifying operators as free functions:

```
class AlmostInt
{
    int value;

public:

    AlmostInt& operator+=(AlmostInt that)
    {
        value += that.value;
        return *this;
    }

    AlmostInt& operator-=(AlmostInt that)
    {
        value -= that.value;
        return *this;
    }

    AlmostInt& operator*=(AlmostInt that)
    {
        value *= that.value;
        return *this;
    }
};

AlmostInt operator+(AlmostInt lhs, AlmostInt rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}

AlmostInt operator-(AlmostInt lhs, AlmostInt rhs)
{
    lhs -= rhs;
    return lhs;
}

AlmostInt operator*(AlmostInt lhs, AlmostInt rhs)
{
    lhs *= rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

This should have the potential to get rid of some unnecessary overhead.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. The great news is this class doesn't match the performance of the inbuilt `int` even on plain old G++ on an x86 linux machine. So I'm going to post a benchmark case so everyone can see what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of your own class, you could do things with a collection of `#define`s so:

```
// For normal operations
#define specialplus +
#define specialmultiple *

// And a separate compilation with
#define specialplus min
#define specialmultiple +
```

Maybe better as:

```
// normalmath.c
#define plus(a,b) (a)+(b)
#define star(a,b) (a)*(b)
#define FUNCTYPE normal
#include "yourcode.c"

// tropicalmath.c
#define plus(a,b) min((a),(b))
#define star(a,b) (a)+(b) 
#define FUNCTYPE tropical
#include "yourcode.c"

// yourcode.c
int FUNCTYPE_opp(int x, int y)
{
    // for example
   return star(plus(x,y),52);
}
```

(at least if I haven't messed up my C preprocessor code).

Or at least something of that form? Perhaps with some cunning function naming to allow both types to be used at the same time?

Comment: Cute :) You know, I probably can get what I want (the ability to write cleaner looking C code) with some preprocessor trickery, though I'd feel a bit stupid spending time trying to get C++ operator overloading working efficiently. Still, if nothing better shows up, this probably what I'm going to have to do!

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments by Fumiyo:

Test to see if AlmostInt runs as fast as a normal int on a normal machine:

Here is the code I ran:
It is a matrix multiplication (or attempts to be, I am not sure I got it correct). But anyway it does a lot of multiplication and addition which is what we want to test. It is compiled simply with -O3

In the main() function I run the multiplication 10,000 times.

The result:

```
AlmostInt:    10093876
int           10320511
```

In my books that's identical with our given margin of error.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

#ifdef ALMOST_INT
class AlmostInt
{
    int value;

    public:
    explicit AlmostInt(int i): value(i)  {}
             AlmostInt():      value(0)  {}

    AlmostInt& operator+=(AlmostInt const& that)
    {
        value += that.value;
        return *this;
    }

    AlmostInt& operator-=(AlmostInt const& that)
    {
        value -= that.value;
        return *this;
    }

    AlmostInt& operator*=(AlmostInt const& that)
    {
        value *= that.value;
        return *this;
    }

};

AlmostInt operator+(AlmostInt lhs, AlmostInt const& rhs) { return lhs += rhs; }
AlmostInt operator-(AlmostInt lhs, AlmostInt const& rhs) { return lhs -= rhs; }
AlmostInt operator*(AlmostInt lhs, AlmostInt const &rhs) { return lhs *= rhs; }

#else
typedef int AlmostInt;

#endif


typedef std::vector<AlmostInt>      Vector;
typedef std::vector<Vector>         Matrix;

void mult(Matrix const& a, Matrix const& b, Matrix& r)
{

    for(int x =0; x < 100; ++x)
    {
        for(int y =0; y < 100; ++y)
        {
            AlmostInt   sum(0);
            for(int s = 0;s < 100; ++s)
            {
                sum    += a[s][y] * b[x][s];
            }
            r[x][y] = sum;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Matrix      a(100, Vector(100));
    Matrix      b(100, Vector(100));
    Matrix      r(100, Vector(100));

    clock_t  t   = 0;
    for(int loop=0;loop < 10000; ++loop)
    {
        if ((loop % 100) == 0) std::cout << "Time: " << t << "\n";
        clock_t  s   = clock();
        mult(a, b, r);
        clock_t  e   = clock();
        t += (e-s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which compiler (version) and platform are you using?

Comment: It should not matter. This type of optimization has been in the compiler for ages (I would guess more than a decade). But I did the original test with gcc 4.2 on MAC. I have repeated the test with gcc 4.4 on Linix.